# OkHttp not closing connection on request timeouts

Tags: okhttp

I am setting `readTimeout` and stalling my server (Node.js + express).

I am not getting a socket close from the client.

Is this an expected behaviour ?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 0):

We fixed a bug related to this just yesterday. If you can do us a favor and try the latest code from git master, I'm eager to see if that fixes your problem!

Comment: hi Jesse! From a quick test I did by running your latest build (`okhttp-2.5.0-20150803.053721-26.jar`), it seems that the behaviour is still the same. I won't be available this week to help debug this further unfortunately

Comment: If you can provide a test case that demonstrates the problem, I can fix it.