# OkHttp connection timeout

Tags: android, okhttp

OkHttp lets you set connection timeout like

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(readTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is the following understanding correct?

connection timeout - This is the timeout before a connection was created with server

read timeout - this is the time while the connection is in flight and will time out irrespective of whether data is being read.

Based on this, what will happen to the opened connection during a read timeout? Will OkHttp let the server know the connection was closed due to a timeout? As soon as there is a read timeout, I would like to close the connection with the server. I dont think OkHttp (2.2.0) is sending a socket close to the server. This is probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770119/okhttp-not-closing-connection-on-request-timeouts?rq=1) issue on SO

Answer (score 2):

If OkHttp gives you a Response, you're responsible for closing its response body. The best way to do this is with a try/finally clause.

```
Response response = call.execute();
try {
  String line;
  while ((line = response.body().source().readUtf8Line()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} finally {
  response.body().close();
}
```

Comment: What I am experiencing is, I make a POST to server, the connection is slow, the read time out is 20 seconds, okhttp throws sockettimeoutexception as expected after 20 seconds, but the inflight request still completes after 20 seconds . The client doesnt know that the request was successful because it had timed out. The server might not have received a socket close from the client so it proceeds to action the POST request. will i have to explicitly call cancel() on the request to avoid server from trying to complete the action ?

Comment: If you don’t get a response back, you have nothing to close.

Answer (score 1):

ConnectionTimeOut is the timeout for the TCP handshake to happen. So it is for the connection between the client and its server.

ReadTimeOut is the timeout on waiting to read data. If the server fails to send a byte after the last byte within the timeout, a read timeout error will be raised.

So you the connection will automatically be closed for you. So you have to just have to perform exception handling.